# How to display 2 separate images in Android OpenGL 2.0 then upon button click shrink img to nothing and grow new image to normal size

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Main idea is to display 2 square images and then upon button click they should shrink to nothing then display a new image from nothing and grow to normal size. (if possible I'd also like to add a rotation as it shrinks and grows)

I've followed http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html
but as I don't have access to an android device till tomorrow I have no way of testing it out right now so I'm hoping anybody might know of existing tutourials which covers anything like this.

I don't want any animation to occur during normal running and it should only occur during my click handler, ofc I still like the images to be displayed till the button clicked just not in motion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the problem is, it is just a simple game of scaling of your object model view.

When you want to scale down ---> you decrease the scaling factor toward zero

Change picture ---> Change binded texture (or change the texture coordinates if you have an atlas)

Scale up ---> increase the scaling factor toward 1.0

Comment: I'm struggling as I'm new to using android and opengl so unless I'm misunderstanding the code I've seen I just don't see how to get certain tasks to happen separately, so it display the images onCreate and then upon button click to only excute the shrink/rotation followed by loading the new image 0 size then grow and rotate.  Right now I just see it as it doing these tasks all at once when the image is 1st displayed.

Comment: link your code, what you have done so far, I will be glad to help you

Comment: I've just been working on this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html but this only shows how to set everything up to work altogether rather than breaking processes down so, Display image, Click to Rotate, etc.  Since I can't test it out today I can't see if it works yet.

Comment: I can only find it setup to work on graphical touch rather than button click unless I'd have to make a button in opengl instead of the main display using a click handler.